# "Math.abs(parseInt($(this).css('left')" returning a different value than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example: [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/z8tpjk1s/)

```
<style>
#slider-outer {
width: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#slider-inner {
width: 1200px;
overflow: visible;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}

#slider-inner div {
background: ;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
}

.a{background: red;}
.b{background: green;}
.c{background: blue;}
.d{background: yellow;}
.e{background: grey;}
.f{background: coral;}
.g{background: olive;}
</style>

<div id="slider-outer">
    <div id="slider-inner">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
        <div class="e"></div>
        <div class="f"></div>
        <div class="g"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#slider-inner').click(function(){

var scrollAmount = $(this).width() - $(this).parent().width();
var currentPos = Math.abs(parseInt($(this).css('left')));
var remainingScroll = scrollAmount - currentPos;
var nextScroll = Math.floor($(this).parent().width() / 2);

if (remainingScroll < nextScroll) {
  nextScroll = remainingScroll;
}

if (currentPos < scrollAmount) {
  $(this).animate({'left':'-=' + nextScroll}, 'slow');

   console.log(currentPos)
} 

else {
  $(this).animate({'left':'0'}, 'fast');
}
});
});
```

I am going through the process of learning jQuery and some javascript and I came across this example of a simple slider and was going through the lines of code and understand how it all works. I understood everything except for the value that the`var = currentPos` returns to the console.

The value returns 0 on the first click, this confuses me as I think it should be `-200px` because the slider-inner is moving `-200px` to the left?

Could someone please explain why the variable is returning the value it is to the console?

Thanks

Comment: The relevant code must be **in** the question, not just linked.

Comment: Animation is done later so variable currentPos will have initial value i.e 0.

Comment: Why the downvote rage? OP made the effort to provide a MCVE and explain what she gets vs. what she expects. Her only sin was not knowing that we expect the code be typed in rather than linked. This is a good question.

Comment: Probably not causing the unexpected results, but as a side note, [always use a `radix` when using `parseInt`](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `console.log` statement is not waiting for the animation to complete and even if it did, `currentPos` will remain at 0, as the animation doesn't alter the value of the variable.

A better way to understand the difference is so:

```
if (currentPos < scrollAmount) {
  $(this).animate({'left':'-=' + nextScroll}, 'slow', function(){
    console.log("After the animation has completed: " + $(this).css('left'));
  });
  console.log("Before the animation has completed: " + $(this).css('left'))
}
```

The third argument to `.animate()` is an anonymous function that will be executed when the animation is finished.

This will output:

```
Before the animation has completed: 0px 
After the animation has completed: -200px
```

Which is hopefully more in line with what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the CSS rule for `#slider-inner`, you'll see that it does not have an explicit `left` set.

```
#slider-inner {
width: 1200px;
overflow: visible;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}
```

Because there is no explicit `left` value, it defaults to `auto`. Since `#slider-inner` is relatively positioned and it also has no `right` property specified, [it receives no offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#Values).

This means `left` is effectively `0px` (which is exactly what you get when you when `$(this).css('left')` runs on the first click). `var currentPos = Math.abs(parseInt($(this).css('left')));` parses that value into an absolute integer, `0`, and stores it in the variable `currentPos`. If you look at all the code that comes after that:

```
    var remainingScroll = scrollAmount - currentPos;
    var nextScroll = Math.floor($(this).parent().width() / 2);

    if (remainingScroll < nextScroll) {
      nextScroll = remainingScroll;
    }

    if (currentPos < scrollAmount) {
      $(this).animate({'left':'-=' + nextScroll}, 'slow');
       console.log(currentPos)
    } 

    else {
      $(this).animate({'left':'0'}, 'fast');
    }
  });
});
```

Nothing in there assigns a new value to `currentPos`, so the value remains `0`. The zero you get from parsing the string into an integer is a literal, not a reference to the current value of `.left`. Even if it were a live reference to the `.left` property of the DOM element, it would not be `-200`, the `.animate` method runs asynchronously, `console.log` is called immediately after it, it might have moved a few pixles to the left in the time between calling `.animate` and the console output, but certainly not the full 200 pixels.

Comment: "This means left is implicitly 0px" Is that right? I thought it is implicitly `auto`, which gives me NaN on the first click.

Comment: @JackZelig Your right, it does default to `auto`, I probably should have said implicitly `auto` which in this case effectively means it is `0px`. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#Values), when used on relatively positioned elements, `auto` calculates the "`left` offset of the element from its original position based on the `right` property, or if right is also auto, do not offset it at all." So in this case where there is no `right` specified either it does not "offset it at all", thus it is effectively `0px`.